# Only tracking code in index page?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics for the first time. I have been waching some videos about how to set up Google Analytics for a website. I'm a little bit confused. In the videos they paste the tracking code only once like in the index.php. Is this really enough? Can Google Analytics track all the activities on all other pages in my website? I thought there should be a unique tracking code for each page on the website or am I thinking wrong here!? Preciate some explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicaly it is enough. You have to put google analytics code to all pages you want to track. You can do it by putting it into for example index.php which is shared by each page. Google analytics will handle all the activities on all pages and you will see results in admin section (reports and other staff).

Comment: Hmm, so I have to put the tracking code once in a page that generates all the other pages then or the same tracking code on each page, is that correct? But how does Google Analytics keep them apart and make them unique?

Comment: Yes. You need to tracking code on all pages that you want to track in google analytics. Please also check this site:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview#howAnalyticsGetsData. Did I helped you?